# How can I replace a character every x line using Notepad++ Find and Replace?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using Find & Replace in Notepad++ to add two new lines and an expression every 100 lines. But I would also like to replace a character at the end of the 100th line but can't seem to achieve / whether it's even possible? 
This is what I have currently:-

**Find What:** (.*\r?\n){1000}\K

**Replace With:** \ninsert  into zipcodes values \n

I have used this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/oJ2yO4/1)

Basically I am trying to turn a normal list into the following:-

Line 99,

Line 100;

insert  into zipcodes values

Line 101,

Line 102,

*Without the line breaks between lines 99-100 / 101-102, I can't seem to get the formatting correct using this text editor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the occurrence of 100 with 99 + single line terminated with `,`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:.*\R){99}.*\K,`
- Replace with: `;\nzipcodes`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much